# Emacs: how to bind action to mac Option (⌥) + arrow key combinations?

Tags: macos, emacs, macports, keymapping, keymaps

I'm using `Emacs` on `OS X` from `mac ports`. By default I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as `Control` key, and <kbd>⌘</kbd> Command as `Meta` key. Thogh, this is quite handy, I'm missing possibility to move cursor one word backward/forward by pressing `M-arrrow key`, i.e. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to move one word forward. What I realy want to have:

- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> move 1 word backward
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> move 1 word forward
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> move to 1st non-whitespace charachter of the line
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> move to the line end
- while in all other cases <kbd>⌘</kbd> ≡ <kbd>Meta</kbd>

I tryed to use in my mappings `(kbd "A-left")`, `"\A-left"`, but this does not worked for me. So, two questions here:

**UPDATED**

> 1. how to create mapping for <kbd>⌥</kbd> `Option` key?

```lisp
(setq mac-option-modifier 'hyper)
;; now you can easily use mappings with Hyper key modifier
```

> 2. how to cerate mapping to arrow keys?

```lisp
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<H-left>") 'left-word)
;; defines Hyper+left arrow combination
```

Comment: What do you get if you type `C-h c` and then `⌥ ←`?

Comment: `<A-left> is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a mac. Could you try following the instructions at the bottom of the page http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

You can use `C-h c` to describe a keybinding by typing it which also returns the string that you have to give as a parameter to `kbd`.

Comment: Super duper! I've mapped my `⌥ Option` key to `Hyper`, after that it's very easy to define keys I want.

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'hyper)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<H><left>") 'left-word)
```

Comment: the trickiest thing I had to do is to find out right syntax to describe exact combination, e.g. `<H-left>`, `H-left` does not worked for me.

Comment: I' a lier. Actually, this `<H-left>` does work , while `<H><left>` does not!